# S6 Android 5.0.2 account sync missing

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, sync, accounts

I cant find option in ANdroid 5.0.2 to disbale or enable sync for a particular apps. 
Say i have 3 accounts and i want to enable contact sync just for one account, but in my case it is enabled for all 3 accounts. same as sync app data which is enabled to all 3 accounts. How do i disable individual app sync?

In my s4 i was able to uncheck a particular app to ignore it from sync, but in s6 i cant find those checkboxes. Not sure if this was changed in Lollipop. Could anyone help me out, please.